# How can I set the minimum order amount from a certain country

Tags: magento-1.9, price, country-regions

I see how I can set the minimum order for all customers, but how can I do this for customers for a certain country, for example France?

In the promotions tab I can set a promotion for a certain country, I would like to know how to do the same for a minimum price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event for "sales_order_place_before" for check the country and total amount of order. So in observer you can write code and fire exception if your condition will not full-fill.

> config.xml

```
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <observersample_event_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Observersample_Event_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>example</method>
                    </observersample_event_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
```

> Observer.php

```
class Observersample_Event_Model_Observer{
    public function example($observer){
          //YOU NEED TO WRITE YOUR CODE HERE FOR CHECK CONDITION
    }
}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/295917/57334  @Rohan Hapani