# Magento 1.9 - What event used for observe Minimum Order Value Condition?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer

Selected customer able to place an order even minimum order condition applied. Eg: My store Minimum order value: 500 if selected customer order value 200 he should place an order.

What event used for this? How to trigger observer?

Comment: Where you want to check the order subtotal?

Comment: At checkout page, if selected customer should be place an order even minimum order value applied.

Comment: For clarity, minimum order value condition not allow to go checkout page, telling minimum order value is 500 in cart page.

Comment: So you want to pass the minimum order condition for selected customer group?

Comment: @Sumit I need minimum order value condition not all applied for selected customer?

Comment: I think you need to override the file contains the minimum order value for the selected customer instead of using an observer for this.

Comment: Yes, how can override the file contains the minimum order value for the selected customer? Is possible to create customer group and added customer list and create shopping cart pricing rule?

Comment: Yes, this will be the best approach. You just need to check the customer group for the logged in customer and pass the minimum order value condition. You need to check this file in the Magento checkout core module and override it.